# Probability Distribution for angle between two random planes

Tags: probability, trigonometry

Given two randomly placed planes what is the probability distribution dependence for the angle $\theta$ between them?

I believe it to be simply $\sin\theta$  but does anyone have a simple proof?

Note: Simple enough to be understood by chemists! I am one such.

Comment: "two randomly placed planes" Perhaps you need to define that

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the angle between the normals, you can reduce the problem to the distribution of the latitudes of points over a half sphere minus $\pi$. $sin(\theta)/2$ is right